# Autocomplete the input during AngularJS autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm using AngularJS [material design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) toolkit from Google.
Below is the `md-autocomplete` directive I'm using:

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.</p>
        <md-autocomplete
            ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
            md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
            md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
            md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
            md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
            md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display" 
            md-min-length="0" 
            placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
            <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>
                No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
                <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
            </md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
        <br>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.simulateQuery">Simulate query for results?</md-checkbox>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.noCache">Disable caching of queries?</md-checkbox>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.isDisabled">Disable the input?</md-checkbox>

        <p>By default, <code>md-autocomplete</code> will cache results when performing a query.  After the initial call is performed, it will use the cached results to eliminate unnecessary server requests or lookup logic. This can be disabled above.</p>
    </form>
</md-content>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

However I want it to look [like this](http://www.codecovers.eu/materialadmin/forms/advanced?headerSearch=#offcanvas-search), to fill out the rest of the text, even though I did not selected any suggestion:

[image]

How can I do this? I would like to do this if possible using Angular material design constructs. I'm a complete novice in CSS realm.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434446/how-to-make-an-autocomplete-just-like-google-auto-suggest-in-angular-ui-select

Comment: I did, but it requires adding additional libraries in my codebase. I was wondering if there is a quick workaround without importing anything else (e.g. some new classes or small code modifications).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with material design, but I did look at the example you shared of what you want.  They just used two overlayed input elements. The autocomplete one (in lighter grey) was absolutely positioned and styled to look like Google's autocomplete.