# Why is an Autocomplete input not updating the model correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm using the following dependencies:

- angularJS v1.5.5
- jquery v1.12.4
- jquery-ui v1.12.1
- jQuery [Autocomplete plugin v1.2.6](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/)

I then define the directive like this:

```
.directive('autoComplete', [
    '$timeout', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var auto;
            auto = function() {
                $timeout((function() {
                    if (!scope[attrs.uiItems]) {
                        auto();
                    } else {
                        element.autocomplete({
                            source: [scope[attrs.uiItems]]
                        });
                    }
                }), 0);
            };
            return auto();
        };
    }
])
```

which I borrowed from the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434446/how-to-make-an-autocomplete-just-like-google-auto-suggest-in-angular-ui-select). The autocomplete works for the most part but when I move across the matches with the keyboard and press return or click on the match with the mouse, the model is updated with only the part that I typed and not with the full item selected. Where should I look to fix this? is it a bug in the plugin? directive? my input definition?

```
$scope.ccyPairs = [ "USDCHF", "CHFUSD", "USDEUR", "EURUSD", "USDGBP", "GBPUSD", "USDJPY", "JPYUSD", "CHFEUR", "EURCHF", "CHFGBP", "GBPCHF", "CHFJPY", "JPYCHF", "EURGBP", "GBPEUR", "EURJPY", "JPYEUR", "GBPJPY", "JPYGBP" ];

<input type="text" auto-complete id="ccyPair" ui-items="ccyPairs" ng-model="ccyPair" />
```

When I do:

```
$scope.$watch("ccyPair", function(newValue, oldValue) {
   console.log(newValue);
}, false);
```

I see that the model is updated only with the part that I type in the input and not with the full selected match in the list either selecting it with a mouse click or moving across the matches and pressing enter.

For example, in the picture below, the model is updated to `USD` only and not to the correct full match `CHFUSD`.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using an angular autocomplete directive instead?  I've lost count of the number of posts asking for help working with jquery based components in angular.  Oil and water in my opinion.

Comment: :D Good point ... where is this angular autocomplete directive? I googled it and I only found jquery plugins :D

Comment: I haven't used one myself but ng-autocomplete looks like it has a good number of downloads.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-autocomplete

Comment: Again I find many many custom ng-autocomplete but which one is the "official one"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "official one" but in general there's no "official" set of components for angular as it is just a javascript framework.  Typically in angular development you pick a ui component library that is based on angular and maybe some css library like Bootstrap.  I'm a big Bootstrap fan so I like the UI Bootstrap library (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) of directives.  Angular Material is another popular one but I have no experience with it.

Comment: The ng-autocomplete one you suggested is only for Google cities etc and not a general implementation ...

Comment: I meant perhaps there was a angular-ui official Angular 1.x extension that included it ...

Comment: Sorry for the bad info on ng-autocomplete.  I didn't read the description close enough.  Anyhow, check out the libraries I mentioned in my previous repsonse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of agony I crawled my way into a working solution :)

```
.directive('autoComplete', [
    '$timeout', function($timeout) {
        return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    var fAutoComplete;
                    fAutoComplete = function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            if (!$scope[attrs.uiItems]) {
                                fAutoComplete();
                            } else {
                                element.autocomplete({
                                    source: [$scope[attrs.uiItems]]
                                }).on('selected.xdsoft', function(e, newValue) {
                                    ctrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                });
                            }
                        }, 5);
                    };
                    return fAutoComplete();
                }
        };
    }
])
```